# How to avoid duplicate joins (Spring data jpa)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When I invoke `findByFlight_Destination()` (that uses sql join under hood) and set annotation @EntityGraph to retrieve the assosiated entity (Flight). There are two duplicate joins instead of one.

Generated sql query

```sql
 Hibernate:
    select
        f1_0.flight_seat_id,
        f1_0.customer_id,
        f1_0.flight_id,
        f3_0.flight_id,
        f3_0.airplane_id,
        f3_0.avia_company_id,
        f3_0.destination,
        f3_0.landing_timestamp,
        f3_0.source,
        f3_0.takeoff_timestamp,
        f1_0.is_window_seat,
        f1_0.position,
        f1_0.price,
        f1_0.class 
    from
        flight_seats f1_0 
    join
        flights f2_0 
            on f2_0.flight_id=f1_0.flight_id 
    join
        flights f3_0 
            on f3_0.flight_id=f1_0.flight_id 
    where
        f2_0.destination=?
```

Repository

```java
public interface FlightSeatRepository extends JpaRepository<FlightSeat, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<FlightSeat> {

  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "flight")
  List<FlightSeat> findByFlight_Destination(City city);
}
```

My entities

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "flight_seats")
public class FlightSeat {

  @Column(name = "flight_seat_id")
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String position;

  @Column(name = "is_window_seat",nullable = false)
  private boolean isWindowSeat;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private int price;

  @Column(name = "class", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @JsonProperty("seat_class")
  private FlightSeatClass seatClass;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @JoinColumn(name = "flight_id", nullable = false)
  @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
  private Flight flight;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
  @JsonIgnore
  private Customer customer;

  // getters, setters and constuctors ommited
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "flights")
@Immutable
public class Flight {

    @Column(name = "flight_id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "takeoff_timestamp", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(value = "takeoff_timestamp")
    private ZonedDateTime takeoffTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "landing_timestamp", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(value = "landing_timestamp")
    private ZonedDateTime landingTimestamp;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private City source;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private City destination;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "avia_company_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private AviaCompany company;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "airplane_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Airplane airplane;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "flight")
    @JsonIgnore
    private final Set<FlightSeat> seats = new HashSet<>();

    // getters, setters and constuctors ommited
}
```

By the way if I remove `@EntityGraph` and set `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` for `flight`, that is

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "flight_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Flight flight;
```

Sql query gets even worse

```sql
Hibernate: 
    select
        f1_0.flight_seat_id,
        f1_0.customer_id,
        f1_0.flight_id,
        f1_0.is_window_seat,
        f1_0.position,
        f1_0.price,
        f1_0.class 
    from
        flight_seats f1_0 
    join
        flights f2_0 
            on f2_0.flight_id=f1_0.flight_id 
    where
        f2_0.destination=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        f1_0.flight_id,
        f1_0.airplane_id,
        f1_0.avia_company_id,
        f1_0.destination,
        f1_0.landing_timestamp,
        f1_0.source,
        f1_0.takeoff_timestamp 
    from
        flights f1_0 
    where
        f1_0.flight_id=?
```

Anyways I need to remove duplicated joins upon using @EntityGraph. I don't want to set fetch type EAGER so that upon every query, the data will be eagerly fetched.